# How to resize tiled windows in KDE?

Tags: kde, window-manager, kwin

Since [KWin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KWin) 4.5 KDE is support tiling. And I'm trying to use it, particularly to change tiled windows size by pressing `modifier key` + `right mouse button` (in compliance with Window Behawior settings), but anything doesn't happens.

I'm doing something wrong or windows resizing is not supported in tiling mode? If it's not supported by default, what is the easiest way to do it by foreign methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I could find is: I set shortcut keys for tiling in System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > select KWin in the drop-down > change Quick Tile Window to the Left/Right. Now I can easily tile a window with Ctrl-Alt-Left, then select the other window I want to tile, and press Ctrl-Alt-Right. If you want those windows to be sized differently instead of 50/50, you can do that manually by dragging the window edges. I don't know if that's possible via keyboard shortcuts.